# Cross compiling libcurl and openssl for A9331

Tags: c, ssl, curl, embedded-linux, openwrt

I am using a dragino product that is basically an arduino Yun running openwrt Linino for an IoT related project. I get data from the arduino part and send json to a firebase DB using libcurl (and HTTPS) in a C program on the openwrt part.
I have managed to setup the cross-compiling toolchain for AR9331 and I can compile simple programs relying on libc. However I need to cross compile libcurl with ssl support in order to send data to firebase with HTTPS. This means that I need to crosscompile openssl. However, i am not sure which option I have to pass to the Configure script in order to set it correctly. Can I compile a static library from openssl and curl so that my program doest have any dependency ? Or is it a bad practice to do so ?

In my last attempt to compile openssl with:

```sh
./Configure  --prefix=$(realpath $LIBPATH)/openssl  linux-mips32
```

where $LIBPATH is the location of my lib in the toolchain.
makes returns the following :

```
apps/speed.o: In function `speed_main':
speed.c:(.text+0x4424): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
speed.c:(.text+0x443c): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
speed.c:(.text+0x4454): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
speed.c:(.text+0x7530): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
speed.c:(.text+0x7544): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `AES_set_decrypt_key'
./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `getcontext'
./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `setcontext'
./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `makecontext'
./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.shared:180: recipe for target 'link_app.gnu' failed
```

How can I compile openssl for the AR9331 ? If i try to add the host flag my architecture is not recognised.
EDIT: Maybe the best method to avoid dependencies problem is to create an ipkg package (openwrt package manager)
I will try it and inform you if this works.

Comment: @FilipKočica if you edit something, do it carefully please. The `<br>` tags don't hurt in normal text, but they become visible in a code block. Also, use `<!-- language: none -->` if a code block isn't actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Those packages should be present in Openwrt by default.
Have you tried downloading them with opkg? maybe you have to check you the repos you are pulling from.

As a last resort you can download OpenWrt source code and build this two packages and then get the .ipkg to your device, OpenWrt build system takes care of getting the toolchain and building everything for you.